# Error when trying to load image file - Vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I am loading a Vue.js image file. That's how I get the error:

> [Vue warn]: Error in event handler for "change": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined"

I also get an error as below. How do I fix it?

> Required fields are full, but empty.

And:

> ["This field is required."]

This is my code:

```
<template>
    ...
    <el-input type="file" @change="onFileChanged"/>
    ...
</template>
<script>
    ...
    methods: {
        onFileChanged(event) {
          const file = event.target.files[0]
          console.log(file)
        },
    }
    ...
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error `event.target` is `undefined` and you are trying to call `files[0]` on `undefined` .

Make sure to pass the argument `$event` to `onFileChanged()` wherever you are calling this method like shown below:

```
<el-input type="file" @change="onFileChanged($event)"/>
```